# Call Pandas Dataframe Functions from a string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For context, I am trying to build a script that will output information about the DataFrames I have in memory.

I have a DataFrame with all the DataFrames listed (dflist). I would like to get the Name of the Dataframe out to call a function. df1.shape for example. I am running into an issue with the system seeing df1 as a string.

dflist
|Name|
|df1 |
|df2 |

Thank You.

Comment: Could you share the code with which you construct the dataframe of dataframes..

Comment: Why don't you keep the dataframes in the list, as opposed to their names?

Comment: I didn't know I could do that, can you share? Wouldn't that start to consume more memory? I am looking at some pretty large tables. Processing isn't a problem.

Comment: Just do `dflist = [df1, df2, df3]` and do `[x.shape for x in dflist]` to get all shapes all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant you have a list of DataFrame names corresponding to the dataframes in memory. In any case, the eval function is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([0, 1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2, 3])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([4, 5])

list_of_names = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

[print(eval(x).shape) for x in list_of_names]
```

Comment: Using `eval()` is a bad idea.

Comment: @NilsWerner, could you elaborate?

Comment: It is insecure as it lets you execute arbitrary code and doesn't express what you are actually trying to do: `eval(x)` could be anything, while `locals()[x]` is the local variable with the name `x`.

Comment: @NilsWerner Agree and deleted  mine ~ thank you for clarify

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Your answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.

Comment: While I see how eval can be dangerous, I wouldn't call it a 'terrible idea' in this case, no?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `locals()`, which returns a dict of all local variables, i.e.

```
df1
```

is the same as

```
locals()['df1']
```

so you can do

```
[locals()[x].shape for x in list_of_names]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since using eval is a bad idea ([Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)), I suggest that you use a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {} 
d['df1'] = pd.DataFrame([0, 1])
d['df2'] = pd.DataFrame([2, 3])
d['df3'] = pd.DataFrame([4, 5])
```

Then, you will be able to iterate through the dataframes to compute the shape or apply any function as follows:

```
In [7]: d.keys() 
Out[7]: ['df1', 'df3', 'df2']

In [8]: [d[x].shape for x in d.keys()]  
Out[8]: [(2, 1), (2, 1), (2, 1)]
```

The extra advantage is that you can easily access any dataframe d['df1'] with no extra memory or speed loss:

```
In [10]: timeit d['df1']
10000000 loops, best of 3: 29.2 ns per loop
```